# iterative regex pattern

Tags: regex, wildcard

I'm trying to find integer values in a script that represents screen coordinates.  The search is simple in a single coordinate check.  However, sometimes the search might be a single coordinate (X,Y) sometimes it might be checking for 2 coordinates, sometimes, 3 or 4.  The problem is that the particular coordinates that I need find in a multiple coordinate scenario might be in any of the positions.  As an example, a 4 coordinate search will have 4 positions with my coordinates being found in any of the 4 positions like this:
where "$" represents the wildcard

IFPIXELEXISTS XPOS="XX,$,$,$" YPOS="YY,$,$,$"

IFPIXELEXISTS XPOS="$,XX,$,$" YPOS="$,YY,$,$"

IFPIXELEXISTS XPOS="$,$,XX,$" YPOS="$,$,YY,$"

IFPIXELEXISTS XPOS="$,$,$,XX" YPOS="$,$,$,YY"

I can't find a way to build the pattern search and the related replace string.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ought to work, where XX and YY are the the coordinates you're looking for:

```
^.*?XPOS=("(XX).*?"|"[^,]*,(XX).*?"|"[^,]*,[^,]*,(XX).*?"|"[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,(XX).*?")\s+YPOS=("(YY).*?"|"[^,]*,(YY).*?"|"[^,]*,[^,]*,(YY).*?"|"[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,(YY).*?").*$
```